# how to save data to mongodb schema with object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I've been trying to save user data to a mongodb schema, sample schema below, the question is how can i insert data inside the object. Please help i've been doing this for hours

e.g. User.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    data:{
        type: String,
        requred: true
    },
    data2:{
        type: String,
        requred: true
    },
    work: {
        industry: String,
        name: String,
        position: String,
    },
    status:{
        type: Boolean,
        default: true,
        requred: true
    },
    subscription:{
        product: String,
        license: String,
        price: String,
        status: Boolean,
        default: false,
        renew: Boolean,
        default : false
    },
    date:{
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

sample registration handling

```
const newUser = new User({
    data1,
    data2,
    work,
    subscription
});

newUser.save()
.then(user => {
    req.flash('success_mg', 'Successfully Registered your can now Login.');
    res.redirect('/login');
})
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: please explain more.. Does this code save `documents` inside your database?

Comment: yes it does save a document in mongodb

Comment: What do u mean by *insert data inside the object*? Do u want to update the saved used data.. or something else.

Comment: did you make DB connection?

Comment: @BloodyLogic of course

Comment: can you provide the code,  upload it somewhere. or follow this https://www.tutorialkart.com/nodejs/mongoose/insert-document-to-mongodb/#:~:text=Mongoose%20%E2%80%93%20Insert%20Document%20to%20MongoDB,argument%20to%20save()%20method.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the _id field, and call your schema like this:

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: id}, {...updates}, {new: true})
 .then(updated_user=>{ DO SOMETHING...  })
```

the **...updates** would be a JSON object containing the keys and values of the properties you're updating.